# Concat and Merge columns with another in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This what look like my dataframe:

| Type | Cat | tax | Car_tax | Type_tax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Car_1 | Car_1_Rent | NW;TAX1/Car_1 | NW;TAX1/Car_1_Rent |
| 1 | Car_2 | Car_2_Rent | NW;TAX1/Car_2 | NW;TAX1/Car_2_Rent |
| 2 | Car_3 | Car_3_Rent | NW;TAX1/Car_3 | NW;TAX1/Car_3_Rent |
| 3 | Car_4 | Car_4_Rent | NW;TAX1/Car_4 | NW;TAX1/Car_4_Rent |
| 4 | Car_5 | Car_5_Rent | NW;TAX1/Car_5 | NW;TAX1/Car_5_Rent |
| 5 | Car_6 | Car_6_Rent | NW;TAX1/Car_6 | NW;TAX1/Car_6_Rent |
| 6 | Car_7 | Car_7_Rent | NW;TAX1/Car_7 | NW;TAX1/Car_7_Rent |
| 23 | Moto_1 | Moto_1_Rent | NW;TAX1/Moto_1 | NW;TAX1/Moto_1_Rent |
| 24 | Moto_2 | Moto_2_Rent | NW;TAX1/Moto_2 | NW;TAX1/Moto_2_Rent |
| 25 | Moto_3 | Moto_3_Rent | NW;TAX1/Moto_3 | NW;TAX1/Moto_3_Rent |
| 26 | Moto_4 | Moto_4_Rent | NW;TAX1/Moto_4 | NW;TAX1/Moto_4_Rent |
| 27 | Moto_5 | Moto_5_Rent | NW;TAX1/Moto_5 | NW;TAX1/Moto_5_Rent |
| 28 | Moto_6 | Moto_6_Rent | NW;TAX1/Moto_6 | NW;TAX1/Moto_6_Rent |
| 29 | Moto_7 | Moto_7_Rent | NW;TAX1/Moto_7 | NW;TAX1/Moto_7_Rent |

And this is what I want to achieve :

| index | Cat | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Car_1 | NW;TAX1/Car_1 |
| 1 | Car_2 | NW;TAX1/Car_2 |
| 2 | Car_3 | NW;TAX1/Car_3 |
| 3 | Car_4 | NW;TAX1/Car_4 |
| 4 | Car_5 | NW;TAX1/Car_5 |
| 5 | Car_6 | NW;TAX1/Car_6 |
| 6 | Car_7 | NW;TAX1/Car_7 |
| 7 | Moto_1 | NW;TAX1/Moto_1 |
| 8 | Moto_2 | NW;TAX1/Moto_2 |
| 9 | Moto_3 | NW;TAX1/Moto_3 |
| 10 | Moto_4 | NW;TAX1/Moto_4 |
| 11 | Moto_5 | NW;TAX1/Moto_5 |
| 12 | Moto_6 | NW;TAX1/Moto_6 |
| 13 | Moto_7 | NW;TAX1/Moto_7 |
| 14 | Car_1_Rent | NW;TAX1/Car_1_Rent |
| 15 | Car_2_Rent | NW;TAX1/Car_2_Rent |
| 16 | Car_3_Rent | NW;TAX1/Car_3_Rent |
| 17 | Car_4_Rent | NW;TAX1/Car_4_Rent |
| 18 | Car_5_Rent | NW;TAX1/Car_5_Rent |
| 19 | Car_6_Rent | NW;TAX1/Car_6_Rent |
| 20 | Car_7_Rent | NW;TAX1/Car_7_Rent |
| 21 | Moto_1_Rent | NW;TAX1/Moto_1_Rent |
| 22 | Moto_2_Rent | NW;TAX1/Moto_2_Rent |
| 23 | Moto_3_Rent | NW;TAX1/Moto_3_Rent |
| 24 | Moto_4_Rent | NW;TAX1/Moto_4_Rent |
| 25 | Moto_5_Rent | NW;TAX1/Moto_5_Rent |
| 26 | Moto_6_Rent | NW;TAX1/Moto_6_Rent |
| 27 | Moto_7_Rent | NW;TAX1/Moto_7_Rent |

I have tried many things but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is named 'd', have you tried:

```
a = d[['Cat', 'Car_tax']].rename(columns={'Car_tax':'Type'})
b = d[['tax','Type_tax']]].rename(columns={'Type_tax':'Type', 'tax':'Cat' })
pd.concat([a,b]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
new_cols = ['Cat', 'Type']

sub_1 = df[['Cat', 'Car_tax']]
sub_2 = df[['tax', 'Type_tax']]
sub_1.columns = sub_2.columns = new_cols

result = pd.concat([sub_1, sub_2]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just append the columns to each other, there is no merge/concat involved:

```py
import pandas as pd


data = {'car1' : ['car10', 'car11'], 'car2': ['car20', 'car21'], 'car3': ['car30', 'car31'], 'car4': ['car40', 'car41']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
car1 = df['car1'].append(df['car2'])
car2 = df['car3'].append(df['car4'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'car1': car1, 'car2': car2})
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: "`DataFrame.append() and Series.append() have been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use pandas.concat() instead`": https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#deprecated-dataframe-append-and-series-append